# Using fstream doesn't write results

Tags: c++

I have a problem with fstream. It takes data from one file but usually it doesn't write it in a result file. I didn't have this problem before and I hadn't changed anything in settings when this started happening. Also restarting computer used to do the trick and it would start working but not anymore.
Example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ifstream in("in.txt");
    ofstream out("out.txt");
    int a;

    in >> a;
    out << a;
    in.close();
    out.close();
    return 0;
}
```

if I write cout << a; it shows the number that was in data file, but with out >> it doesn't change the result file out.txt. All files are in the same folder.

If it makes a difference: I'm using codeblocks

Comment: are you sure you're looking in the right folder ? try delete out.txt and see if the file is being created. also try to do out.flush() before closing.

Comment: Always check that opening the streams works.

Comment: you need to check for errors. Opening a file, reading from, and writing to a file, can all go wrong and your code assumes it all goes right.

Comment: What is the relation to codeblocks?Codeblocks is only the ide and should not change the behavior of your executable.

Comment: @Klaus, sorry, for now I am just learning programming in school so I don't know a lot about programming programs so I didn't knew if this problem is related to codeblocks or fstream itself. I will correct the post, thanks for explaining

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 I think everything is correct because when I restart computer first few times everything works, because it writes results in the correct file. But restarting doesn't always help and/or it stops working after restarting at random times.

Comment: @StPiere I tried your suggestions about deleting out.txt few hours ago and out.flush() and it didn't help, but now I restarted computer so after deleting out.txt it creates a new one after compiling, but it often starts working after restarting, just not always and not for a long time, that's my problem

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 how could I check that? sorry if that's a dumb question